# Information not updating to database after deselecting a checkbox

Tags: php

I am having issues when I untick a checkbox and leave it blank and update my PHP / MySQL  form, the data is not saved in the database. Updates text / date fields are working fine.

Code

```
$learning_opportunities = isset($_POST['learning_opportunities']) ? $_POST['learning_opportunities'] : $contact['learning_opportunities'];

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE contacts SET current_living_situation=?, personal_strengths=?, skills_training=?, currently_spend_time=?,personal_goals=?,housing_situation_transport_childcare=?,
   learning_actual_end_date=?, partcipant_complete_course=?, withdrawal_reason=?,participant_intended_learning=?,pcp_education=?,
   coursestart_date=?,education_provider_name=?,course_title=?,course_level=?,planned_glh=?,in_paid_employment=?,in_paid_employment_start_date=?,
   in_paid_employer_name_address=?,in_paid_job_title=?,in_paid_contracted_hour=?,not_in_paid_employment=?,pcp_gap_year=?, 
   pcp_others=?,pcp_voluntary_work=?,destination_progression_date=?,destination_progression_collection_date=?,project_officer_name=?,
   project_officer_signature=?,project_officer_date=?,participant__name=?,participant__signature=?,participant__date=?,
   final_assessment_progress_you_made=?,final_assessment_progress_your_goal=?,final_assessment_progress_your_reach_goal=?,
   final_assessment_progress_overall=?,final_assessment_participat_name=?,final_assessment_participat_signature=?,
   final_assessment_participat_date=?,final_assessment_project_worker_name=?,final_assessment_project_worker_signature=?,
   final_assessment_project_worker_date=?,learning_opportunities=?,contact_for_other_purposes=?,empowering_communities=?,empowering_communities_name=?,empowering_communities_sign=?,empowering_communities_date=?,
   participant_enrolled_onto=?,participant_moved_another_provider=?,participant_eligible_free_school=?,british_passport=?,
   eec_passport=?,euss_via_home=?,preferred_evidence=?,provide_preferred_evidence=?,option_adoption_vertificate=?,option_driving_licence=?,
   option_non_eu_passport=?,option_biometric_immigration=?,option_current_immigration=?,option_marriage_civil_partnership=?,
   option_other_evidence=?,option_nine=?,details_evidence_provided=?,dwp_job_centre_letter=?,confirmation_relevant_organisation=?,self_certification_evidence=?,
   partcipant_told_support=?,participant_file_completed_remotly=?,declaration_name_please_print=?,declaration_job_title=?,declaration_organisation=?,
   declaration_signature_date=?,declaration_signature=? where id = ?');
  
  $result = $stmt->execute([$current_living_situation,$personal_strengths,$skills_training,$currently_spend_time,$personal_goals,
  $housing_situation_transport_childcare,$learning_actual_end_date,$partcipant_complete_course,$withdrawal_reason,$participant_intended_learning,$pcp_education,
  $coursestart_date,$education_provider_name,$course_title,$course_level,$planned_glh,$in_paid_employment,$in_paid_employment_start_date,
  $in_paid_employer_name_address,$in_paid_job_title,$in_paid_contracted_hour,$not_in_paid_employment,$pcp_gap_year,$pcp_others,
  $pcp_voluntary_work,$destination_progression_date,$destination_progression_collection_date,$project_officer_name,$project_officer_signature,
  $project_officer_date,$participant__name,$participant__signature,$participant__date,$final_assessment_progress_you_made,
  $final_assessment_progress_your_goal,$final_assessment_progress_your_reach_goal,$final_assessment_progress_overall,$final_assessment_participat_name,
  $final_assessment_participat_signature,$final_assessment_participat_date,$final_assessment_project_worker_name,$final_assessment_project_worker_signature,
  $final_assessment_project_worker_date,$learning_opportunities,$contact_for_other_purposes,$empowering_communities,$empowering_communities_name,$empowering_communities_sign,$empowering_communities_date,
  $participant_enrolled_onto,$participant_moved_another_provider,$participant_eligible_free_school,$british_passport,
  $eec_passport,$euss_via_home,$preferred_evidence,$provide_preferred_evidence,$option_adoption_vertificate,$option_driving_licence,
  $option_non_eu_passport,$option_biometric_immigration,$option_current_immigration,$option_marriage_civil_partnership,$option_other_evidence,$option_nine,
  $details_evidence_provided,$dwp_job_centre_letter,$confirmation_relevant_organisation,$self_certification_evidence,$partcipant_told_support,
  $participant_file_completed_remotly,$declaration_name_please_print,$declaration_job_title,$declaration_organisation,$declaration_signature_date,
  $declaration_signature, $_POST['id']]);
  
  if($result == true){
      $details = "<b>All Data Updated</b>";
      // Insert new record into the contacts table
          $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT IGNORE INTO client_activity (id,client_id,date,time,details,username) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)');
        $client_activity = $stmt->execute([ null,$_POST['id'],date("Y/m/d"),date("H:i:s"),$details,$_SESSION['name'] ]);
        if($client_activity == true){
          $msg = 'Updated Successfully!';
```

Form code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="learning_opportunities" value="learning_opportunities" <?php if($contact['learning_opportunities']=="Yes"){ echo 'checked'; } ?>> About courses or learning opportunities.<br>
```

I have read countless articles and tutorials and can't get it to update the data.

Comment: Something like: `$learning_opportunities = isset($_POST['learning_opportunities']) ? "yes" : "no";`

Comment: You should really shorten that query to the bare minimum next time. At this moment it makes the question harder to read than it actually is

Answer (score 1):

The assignment of the variable `$learning_opportunities` does not make any sense at all.
Only checked checkboxes are sent to the server.

The following snippet will just force the checkbox to be set back to `true` if the old value `$contact['learning_opportunities']` was already `true`, making it impossible to uncheck the checkbox

```
$learning_opportunities = isset($_POST['learning_opportunities']) ? $_POST['learning_opportunities'] : $contact['learning_opportunities'];
```

If you want to be able to update that field you just need this assignment:

```
$learning_opportunities = isset($_POST['learning_opportunities']) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: thanks for this, it's helped deselect the checkbox but does not allow me to re-select the checkbox?

Comment: What's the datatype of the corresponding field?

Comment: The database datatype is varchar(225)

Comment: You might want to change that to tinyint(1) for boolean values. See my edit if you really want to use varchar though

Comment: I've updated as suggested and modified some of the code and appears to be working fine now. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

After sending the form with the checkboxes keep in mind, that there are 2 scenarios possible:

1. if you checkbox was checked you will get `"on"` in `$_POST['learning_opportunities']`.
2. if your checkbox wasn't checked you will not get `'learning_opportunities'` index in the `$_POST` array at all

Check this demo:

**index.php**

```php
<?php

$contact['learning_opportunities'] = isset($_POST['learning_opportunities']) ? "yes" : "no";

?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="learning_opportunities" <?= $contact['learning_opportunities'] === "yes" ? 'checked' : "" ?>>
    About courses or learning opportunities.
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```